# Printing object from neighbour object inside parent object causes 'undefined' message

Tags: javascript, oop

I was working with objects some moments ago, but a problem occured and I don't know how to solve it :( First of all, I made parent object `O`, then child objects called `A` and `B`. But when I want to get `B` object from `A`, JavaScript alerts it's undefined :/

---

Here's the code:

```
var A = function() {
    alert(O.b);
}

var B = function() {}

var O = function() {
  this.b = new B();
  this.a = new A();
}

var o = new O();
```

## [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c4Ldr3n9/3/)

Is there a way how to solve it? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `O` is the constructor function, not an instance of the object. `o` is an instance of the object.  So, `o.b` would get you a reference to a B object, but `O.b` is not something you have defined as your constructor function has no properties you've added.

Comment: @jfriend00 is right, the problem is `o` does not exist when you try to alert it's `b`, so you need to pass `this` in order to do what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @jfriend00 o.b causes error in console, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'b' of undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way it could work:

```
var A = function(thatO) {
    alert(thatO.b);
}

var B = function() {}

var O = function() {
  this.b = new B();
  this.a = new A(this);
}

var o = new O();
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Is this only way to do it, like without passing `O` to `A`? :)

Comment: If you need it to happen inside the `O` constructor, I believe it is the only way.   Anyway, even with a different solution that don't require an inside-constructor action, you need the global `o`, if you want me to edit with this kind of option - I can do that :)

Comment: BTW, if you want to share your actual needs from this structure, there might be a better way to build it in the first place in order to do it in a "cleaner" way.

Comment: I've got huge code, so I'll do it like you did, thanks anyway! :)